# How to concatenate optional String in SWIFT

Tags: swift, string-concatenation

I want to concatenate a string, and I do this:

```
var text: String!
....
text = "hello" 
text += "! How r you?"
```

But I got the following error:

> cannot convert value of type 'String!' to expected argument type
>   'inout String' text += "!" ^~~~

How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: change `var text: String!` to `var text = ""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to append something to an optional, but only if it's not nil, you should put a question mark after the variable's name.

```
text? += "appended text"
```

Comment: Or `text? += "! How r you?"`

Comment: @Hamish You are right. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the variable without the exclamation mark, like that :

```
var text: String = ""
text = "hello" 
text += "! How r you?"
```

Or shorter in function of the context:

```
var text: String = "hello" 
text += "! How r you?"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by doing this

```
var text = "Hello!" as! String
text = text + " How are you?"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

When handling exclamation points in Swift, you have to remember that trying to use `!` to access a nonexistent optional value **triggers a runtime error**.

If an optional has a value, it is considered to be **“not equal to nil”**. So you have to check this before you can access to its underlying value:

```
if text != nil {
    text += "! How are you?"
}
```